# How custom fontFamily Chip rect material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to custom font famaily Chip but it doesn't work .................................................................................................................................................

```js
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core';
import overrides from './overrides';
import palette from './palette';
import typography from './typography';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette,
  typography,
  overrides,
});

export default theme;
```

```js
import MuiChip from './MuiChip';
import MuiTooltip from './MuiTooltip';

export default {

  MuiTooltip,
  MuiChip
};
```

```js
export default {
chip: {
    fontFamily: ['prompt'].join(',')
  }
};
```

Comment: 1. Your code shows a theme but I cant see where you implemented it in App.js or such.
2. I don't think that HoC will do what you think it does.
3. Since you are using materialUI you might as well just use `makeStyles` for that one chip. Look up for it in the materialUI documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the default theme by using createMuiTheme and then wrap the component under as below

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiChip: {
            root: {
                padding: '3px 4px',
                fontFamily: "'Bree Serif', sans-serif",
                fontSize: "15px"
            },
        },
    },
});

export default Component = props => {
   return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Chip size="small" label="Basic" />
        </ThemeProvider>
   );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mui version 5 syntax

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

export const chipTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiChip: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          height: '20px',
        },
        label: {
          color: 'pink',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```